# tshark display filter not working while writing pakets to an outfile

Tags: networking, wireshark, tshark

Am new to tshark.I wanto capture some ipp data using wireshark

for that am using following tshark terminal commnd

```
 tshark -i 3 -a duration:20 -Y "ipp contains 02:00:00" -T pdml > gggggg.xml
```

In the above command am setting a duration of 20 sec after that tshark execution wil stop automaticlly and created an xml file

it is working properly fine

But some situations there is a delay in getting `'ipp'` data and after 20 sec tashark caputing will stops .due this am not able to caputure the data.it exits after 20 sec. when i increase the time delay i will get the full data as xml file. Am looking another options like setting the file size and when the file size reaches particular `kb` stop `tshark`.for that i changed the tshark command as

```
tshark -i 3 -Y "ipp contains 02:00:00" -b filesize:100 -b files:1 -l -w some.txt -T pdml > gggggg.xml
```

am getting the error

```
 tshark: Display filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured packets.
```

How can i crerate an xml file with and when the file size reaches particular Kbs stop the tshark execution.also i need to use filter type as `"ipp contains 02:00:00"`(it will only outputs ipp packets data as xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Wireshark / TShark, there is two kind of filters with different syntax : [capture filters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) and [display filters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters). For your situation, you can set a capture filter retaining only TCP or UDP packets going to port 631 (IPP):

```
dst port 631
```

To limit the size of the capture file, the [man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) says:

> -a  < capture autostop condition >
>
> Specify a criterion that specifies when TShark is to stop writing to a capture file.  The criterion is of the form test:value,
>   where
>              test is one of:
>
> filesize:value Stop writing to a capture file after it reaches a size of value kB.

So, for a maximum file size of 1Mb, with xml output and a capture filter on destination port 631 (IPP), your command will look like:

```
tshark -i eth0 -f "dst port 631" -a filesize:1024 -T pdml -w ipp.xml
```